# Are TV specials on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Final TV Decision](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220/final-tv-decision)

Rudolph the Red-Nosed Reindeer (1964) is a 47 minute long *TV special* that aired on NBC and then later on CBC. The narrative goes something like

*Rudolph has a glowing red nose and his activities on the North Pole*

Seeing that

- It was not originally released for theatre
- There are various versions broadcasted of this picture

Should this be on-topic? I am going with yes.

---

I ask that you refrain from using the logic that the site is called movies.se. *This is flawed logic, because no one gave a reason to this question and the reason why the TV merge was declined*

https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2817/why-not-merge-movies-and-television-and-give-both-a-chance

36 votes on the question, 29 on the answer saying yes to merge.

It's called movies.se because it launched from Area 51 as such. That's all. It needed a name.