# Scripted sport entertainment shows

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Scripted entertainment shows like wwe network, wrestling brands all across the world, talk shows, chat shows can be labeled as on topic questions? If somebody has a question, is it okay and is it on-topic asking here?

Comment: Seems on topic to me but the question **content** will be the determining factor.

Comment: Recall, we're not a discussion forum or a message board. We're not here to chat or speculate, **definite** and **specific** questions are required.

Comment: [Is a question on WWE on topic?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1449/is-a-question-on-wwe-on-topic)

Comment: Note also we have a [tag:wwe] tag but it's **not** frequented. It only has 9 questions out of over 16,500 on this site.

Comment: I didn't just meant only about wwe. it could be anything. not even only sports. live shows, streamings, chat shows, interview shows and what about music videos and short films?

Comment: Off-hand I would sugegst that most of those are **off-topic**. Have you read the [guide](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: Note that *"TV news, sports and current affairs*" are **specifically off-topic**. I would suggest, if you are in any doubt...ask about your proposed question in Meta **first** and see what the community thinks *before* you post it on the main site. Or ask in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1888/the-screening-room)

Comment: Refer [Why limit the scope of television?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246/why-limit-the-scope-of-television) and [Scope: Award/Beauty/Contest Shows?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2011/scope-award-beauty-contest-shows) too then

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WWE production and storyline questions are on topic. [Is a question on WWE on topic?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1449/is-a-question-on-wwe-on-topic) The sport related questions are not. Same with Game shows. Ex: Why was character x made a heel? Ex: How is jeopardy filmed? Off topic example: are pile drivers safe? Why do vowels cost money on wheel of fortune?

Talk/chat show production questions are on topic, as are any tv or movie production questions. But the topic of the day is not. These show topics have no artistic value which is our main focus on this site. Ex: how does talk show ex find it's guests. Off topic example: why did Crystal cheat on Matt in episode 62829 of Jerry springer.

Music videos are only allowed if it's about a storyline question, or a production question. Key example is a question about Michael Jackson's Thriller, and if Michael and the girl were really in the movie in the video.

Short films are on topic. Only criteria is that they be professionally made, not some shitty amateur webcam attempt.

Comment: "shitty ameature webcam attempt"

@Cde
 sometimes those are the strangest and very good on story-line, most could be bad. but I don't think criticizing amateur work and camera quality people may have is a good way to go.
Appreciate the answer though

Comment: Nice explanation. Mention of Thriller video as an example, good.

Comment: @vishwa a bit arbitrary yes I know but that's where the line got drawn.